# Which one would be best in use for to show read only data in asp.net ? repeater or html created at runtime?

Tags: asp.net

I have a scenario where we need to show data in tabular form.
there will be 10 different data tables in form so which approach will be good to use:
1. Create html table at runtime based on data.
2. Use asp.net's repeater control.

Main criteria is performance, page should not take more time to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A repeater generates HTML.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Yes i know repeater generates html. Plz read question carefully main concern is performance. If we use 10 asp.net control(repeater) then performance will be fast or if we create all 10 html tables at run time?

Comment: I did read the question.  There is no improvement in performance creating your own html.  It will save you alot of programming time by using the built-in functionality.

Answer (score 0):

TheGeek's answer is valid.  The custom html code you are about to write will not be very different from the code the repeater control is writing.

If performance is your main concern, you should consider using lazy loading.